# Can a macroscopic passive system break the time-reversal symmetry spontaneously?

Tags: symmetry-breaking, time-reversal-symmetry

I know there are many systems can break T-symmetry if the internal source ALREADY chooses a direction of T. Without any driving source inside the system, can T-symmetry be broken spontaneously?

Comment: Yes, like ferromagnets.

Comment: I would consider ferromagnetism has a quantum mechanical origin of spin alignment and hence it is microscopic. I am wondering whether there is a truly macroscopic one...

Comment: You certainly see ferromagnetism as a macroscopic phenomena, don't you?. The exchange interactions that ultimately drive ferromagnetism have a quantum mechanical origin, but apart from that, it is almost classical. But in the end of the day, the world is quantum mechanical. Just have to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is it possible to have a T-symmetry broken arising from macroscopic properties instead of spin on a quantum level?

Comment: A ball rolling down the hill into a flat valley will never roll back up again.